# Why can only duration "once" be used on orders in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've gotten an error code back from using a stripe coupon which says:

> Only coupons with duration "once" can be applied to orders. The coupon code that you supplied (TESTCOUPON) has duration "forever."

So, fixing this is seems pretty direct, change the duration to "once."  But when looking through the docs, I haven't been able to figure out why.

In this section of the docs: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts#creating-coupons

It states that duration can be `once, forever, or repeating`.  But I can't find anywhere that explains clearly what these three are, specifically as applies to why only one of them can be applied to orders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I suppose it makes more sense once you know what "orders" are defined as.  Essentially, there's "products" which are really subscriptions, which can have plan types.  But an "order" is for a one off payment for something that would normally be a product or service, but is instead just an "order."

Point being, it's a one off payment, a coupon code can only be applied once.

If doing a subscription, you could have:

- once: discount happens on first payment
- forever: repeats every payment
- repeating: you set some extra parameters on how many times it'll repeat

But on an order, it's only bought once.

Comment: `duration_in_months` is used in combination with `duration === 'repeating'` to set number of monthly repetitions